# Extract all audio streams from video into seperate audio files using ffmpeg and python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract all the audio streams/tracks (whatever you wanna call them) from a video and save each one to a separate audio file using python and ffmpeg.
The problem is, I would need to know how many audio streams there are and I don't want to have to enter the number of streams the file has manually nor do I want to run a ffmpeg command for each file to figure it out.
Is there a way for the program to figure out how many streams there are so I can extract each stream to a separate file?

Here is a snippet of the code
`inputFiles` is a list of directories to each video file being inputted
`_dir_in` is the directory that all the input files are in
`_dir_out` is the directory all the files outputted by the code are placed

```py
for video in inputFiles:
    number_of_audio_streams = 0 # this is where I need to know how many audio streams there are
    for i in range(number_of_audio_stremas):
        subprocess.call(f'ffmpeg -i {_dir_in}/{video} -map 0:a:{str(i)} {_dir_out}/audio/{video}-{str(i)}.m4a')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic method using `ffmpeg` alone to extract all audio streams.

You can use `ffprobe` to determine the number of audio streams/tracks:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=nw=1 input.mkv
  codec_type=audio
  codec_type=audio
  codec_type=audio
```

This example shows that `input.mkv` has 3 audio streams.

You can parse this however you like to get the total number. Example using `wc -l`:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=nw=1 input.mkv | wc -l
  3
```

Should be a good start for you implement a solution in Python (I don't know Python well enough to give you a copy and paste answer).

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. I had to use a different cmd instead of `wc -1` because I'm on windows lol

Comment: @Insberr What is the Windows equivalent?

Comment: I used `find /c /v ""`